# Doctrine 2.1 where foreign key id =?, edit: Fixed in Doctrine 2.2

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I've looked at a lot of answers here related to what seems to be a serious lack of functionality in Doctrine 2.1 that may be the result of OOP correctness trumping relational sanity.

I have two tables with a many to one relationship, Articles and Members.  A Member can have many published Articles. The annotation on the owning side is

```
/**
 * @var \Member
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Member")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
 private $member;
```

I want to get all active articles for member 6, this is a simple query in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mbr_article 
   WHERE active = 1 AND member_id = 6 
   ORDER BY article_id DESC
```

What I ended up with was

```
$rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SMWMemberBundle:Article');
$q = $rep->createQueryBuilder('a')
     ->leftJoin('a.member','m')    
     ->where('m.id = ?1')
     ->andWhere('a.active = 1')
     ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC')
     ->setParameter(1, $id)    
     ->getQuery();
```

which generated

```
SELECT m0_.id AS id0, m0_.active AS active1, m0_.update_time AS update_time2,
       m0_.content AS content3, m0_.member_id AS member_id4 
   FROM mbr_article m0_ 
   LEFT JOIN mbr_member m1_ ON m0_.member_id = m1_.id 
   WHERE m1_.id = ? AND m0_.active = 1 
   ORDER BY m0_.id DESC
```

which works and probably isn't much slower, but that JOIN is not needed as I already have the Member object.  When I tried it the other way, I got all Articles not just active ones.

I've seen responses such as [Can you get a foreign key from an object in Doctine2 without loading that object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211679/can-you-get-a-foreign-key-from-an-object-in-doctine2-without-loading-that-object) that use `getEntityIdentifier` and mentions improvements coming in the 2.2 where I could say `IDENTITY(member)`.

Is there a reasonable way to do this in Doctrine 2.1? Will the enhancement allow `andWhere('IDENTITY(member) = ?')` in the query builder?

Edit:

Thanks to @Ocramius, ->where('IDENTITY(a.member) = ?1') does work in Doctrine 2.2

Comment: First of all, consider that 2.1 does not have support anymore: you should consider upgrading. Anyway, retrieving the identifier from a proxy doesn't cause it to load if the method name is `'get' . ucfirst($fieldName)`

Comment: @Ocramius Thank you, `->where('IDENTITY(a.member) = ?1')` does work in Doctrine 2.2, could you please post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Add it yourself and accept it, after all you found the solution yourself ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IDENTITY works in WHERE clauses generated by query builder in Doctrine 2.2 eg.

```
$q = $rep->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->where('IDENTITY(a.member) = ?1')
    ->andWhere('a.active = 1')
    ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter(1, $id)    
    ->getQuery();
```

produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT m0_.id AS id0, m0_.active AS active1, m0_.update_time AS update_time2, 
       m0_.content AS content3, m0_.member_id AS member_id4 
    FROM mbr_article m0_ 
    WHERE m0_.member_id = ? AND m0_.active = 1 
    ORDER BY m0_.id DESC
```